# jQuery wrap each list in a ul tag

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

Without going into details, I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("nav ul ul").each(function () {
    var navitems = $(this).html();
    alert(navitems);
});
```

I knopw .html uses InnerHTML so the alerts are all

```
<li>xxxxx</li>
<li>xxxxx</li>
```

But how can edit the jQuery so the alerts are like

```
<ul>
<li>xxxxx</li>
<li>xxxxx</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$("nav ul ul").each(function () {
    var navitems = "<ul>" + $(this).html() + "</ul>";
    alert(navitems);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("nav ul ul").each(function () {
        var navitems = $(this).html();
        var tag = $(this).get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase();
        alert('<' + tag + '>' + navitems + '</' + tag + '>');
});
```

Comment: I like the idea, but .attr("tag") doesn't work. What about $(this).get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase()?

Comment: you could use var ´tag = $(this).context.localName´

Answer (score 1):

i would do something like this:

```
$("nav ul ul").each(function () {
   alert( $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).remove().html() );
 });
```

it creates a dummy div, appends the selected UL in it and removes the dummy and gives you back its html content.

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/QmTSF/

Answer (score 0):

i don't really know what exactly you want. but as I see it, the parent() selector could help.

http://api.jquery.com/parent/